# Loading data in a Kendo Window with AJAX when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have an mvc razor page that has several product items listed on it using a razor foreach loop:

```
@foreach (var product in Model)
{
    <h2>@product.Title</h2>
    <div>product.Description</div>

    <a href="#" class="lnkViewRatings">View Reviews</a>
}
```

**My goal:**
On the click of any link with the css class 'lnkViewReviews' on it I would like the kendo window to open and display a listing of all of the Reviews for that product using an ajax request. The request will be of type GET and depending on the product where the link was clicked the data param will be the productId.

Here is exactly that I would like (please tell me if there is a better way to do it also):

1. User clicks View Reviews link by one of the listed products.
2. A dialog window opens up and pulls in the list of that products reviews in some sort of template that I can specify.

Below is my attempt based on the kendo documentation, but I am having problems. Can you please show me a good way to achieve this?

HTML

```
<div id="dialog">
    <p>This is static text in my dialog window</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
    visible: false
});
var dialog = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");

$(".lnkViewReviews").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    dialog.refresh({
        url: "/Products/GetReviews",
        data: { productId: $(this).attr('data-product-Id') },
    });

    dialog.open().center();
});
```

**The asp.net MVC controller action method:**

```
public IActionResult GetReviews(int productId)
{
    var prodReviews = _repository.GetProductReviews(productId);

    return Json(prodReviews);
}
```

Comment: `but I am having problems`. What is the problem ? Error message?

Comment: No error message specifically, but nothing is working properly. Does it look like I am on the right track? I am trying to figure out how to list the returned data in the window with templating and additionally how to pass the product id to the click event.

Comment: Is your problem only passing the procuctId? I think rest of your code looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`From your comments`

> how to pass the product id to the click event.

You can use the new data-* attribute to hold on values in any element.

```
 @foreach (var product in Model)
    {
        <h2>@product.Title</h2>
        <div>product.Description</div>

        <a href="#" data-product-Id="@product.Id" class="lnkViewRatings">View Reviews</a>
    }
```

And your Jquery can be

```
$(".lnkViewReviews").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    dialog.refresh({
        url: "/Products/GetReviews",
        data: { productId: $(this).attr('data-product-Id') } //You can retrieve product Id from the element itself
    });

    dialog.open().center();
});
```

Comment: You really helped me achieve one of my problems. I had no idea about the new data attribute. This is going to be a life saver when using jQuery. Before this I was doing things like onclick="return myFunction(@product.Id)".. I guess the only thing I have to figure out now is how to use the kendo template system to list all of the product reviews inside of the window. As of now I see the json in the window.

Comment: Are you initially getting the window with template right? like by hardcoding the values as in Kendo demo site?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but no only when the user clicks the link I want to add the template in dialog.refresh. Here is the documentation I am looking at: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-content.template I believe I just need to figure out how to do a forloop on the json data and output what I need. Here is the other documentation I am looking at: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-refresh However, they only show simple template examples.. I have a list of Product Reviews as json for my data.

Comment: Yes I understand, take a look here in this example http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/index and make sure it get this working first. Later you can make it open only on user click.

Comment: Yes, I have it working just like the Basic Example to initialize the window with whichever div I specify to be the window. The only difference is I that I removed .data("kendoWindow").center().open(); since I don't want to do that on page load like they have it. I updated my code to show the exact JavaScript I have so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104131/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-reddy).